# Calendar adds one hour to whatever time I set

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, calendar

When I create a new event and set the time to 12:00, it turns into 13:00 right before my eyes, on the new event creation screen. How do I fix this madness?

I've googled this issue for a while and I don't think it's just the daylight saving time thing everyone else is having. My time zone is Moscow and we recently stopped saving time, so there's no option to select between +3 and +4 time zones.

My device is HTC 626g+ and I'm having this problem with the default calendar app.